# Login URL in Default WordPress Welcome eMail

Tags: wordpress, authentication, custom-wordpress-pages

My WordPress Website welcome email comes as:

Username: xxxxxxxx

To set your password, visit the following address:

https://mywebsite.com/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=xxxxxxxxxxx&login=USERNAME

https://mywebsite.com/wp-login.php

How to change URL Format to my current custom login page:

https://mywebsite.com/MY-CURRENT-LOGIN-PAGE?action=rp&key=xxxxxxxxxxx&login=USERNAME

https://mywebsite.com/MY-CURRENT-LOGIN-PAGE

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use the `login_url` ([WordPress docs on login_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_url/)) hook. Something like below. Just place that code in your theme's function.php file.

```
add_filter( 'login_url', 'my_custom_login_url', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Filters the login URL.
 *    
 * @param string $login_url    The login URL. Not HTML-encoded.
 * @param string $redirect     The path to redirect to on login, if supplied.
 * @param bool   $force_reauth Whether to force reauthorization, even if a cookie is present.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function my_custom_login_url( $login_url, $redirect, $force_reauth ){

    // This will append /the-url-to-login/ to you main site URL as configured in general settings (ie https://mywebsite.com/the-url-to-login/)
    // Replace '/login/' and '/account/' with your desired path.
    $login_url = site_url( '/login/', 'login' );
    $redirect  = site_url( '/account/' );
    
    if ( ! empty( $redirect ) ) {
        $login_url = add_query_arg( 'redirect_to', urlencode( $redirect ), $login_url );
    }
  
    return $login_url;
}
```

Think `add_filter` as proof reading and editing. You have some text that is about to be published but you send it to a person to proof read and edit. The edits they make are what actually get published.

When you use `add_filter` you can do anything you want with that text. Whatever comes out gets used. You can even ignore the original text and pass along your own.

Comment: I am sorry for the silly response, but i am have no developing experience and i dont understand most of the code, but anyway may pages are:

account page: /account/

login page: /login/

so, is it as simple as replacing $login_url with /login/ and $redirect with /account/ or not i am messing things out!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @weegoz I just updated the comment with some more details. If that solves your problem, please mark it as the answer. :-)

Comment: Hello...
Thanks for your help...

This is the new email response new registered users received:

Username: xxxxxxxxx

To set your password, visit the following address:

https://website.com/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=4NkIt86sdfsdfsdfsfds4&login=USERNAME

https://website.com/login/?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2F**WEBSITE.COM**%2Faccount%2F


So its kind of duplicated link, one fixed and one as is before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So its kind of duplicated link, one fixed and one as is before.

So far from having duplicate links, the new link redirect user to login page, but it doesn't have the key as in the original link, so user doesn't verify directly

I will try to elaborate may be i wrongful described my issue, What i mainly need is the same standard email goes to client, but the link in this email goes with my custom login page, not with standard WordPress login page, so instead of anything/wp-login.php ; it should be anything/login/

Comment: If you just want to effect emails, you could use the [wp_mail hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_mail/) to change text in the message. There are also plugins that let you customize emails. That may be easier if you don't have any developing experience.

You could setup the email to say whatever URL you want and then use .htaccess to add a redirect to the actual login page.